# Huawei Mobile Services PUSH message cannot reach China users

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-push-notification

I am a US HUAWEI developer, I have integrated Huawei Mobile Services Push Kit, I can send and receive Push messages on phones outside of China, however I cannot send to nor receive from phones inside China (Huawei or non-Huawei phones with HMS Core). I set my data storage in Germany, is there any reason why my Push messages cannot reach inside China? What should I do to make it work for phones inside China? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What push message are you sending? Notification messages or Data messages? It is better to put your logs here. We will analyze it and give you the reason ASAP.

Comment: Besides, what does it mean by "inside China". Is it a mobile phone in China locationally? Or it is a Chinese phone (but in not in China)?

Comment: Yes, I mean the mobile phones physically located in China. My issue is more procedural than technical. I know how to send messages technically. I can send and receive messages between phones outside of China, but I could not send to or receive from phones located in China. I think I must go through special application/procedures.

Huawei PUSH service requires selecting a "Data storage location."  I currently selected Germany. I suspect that I need to select China, but the system won't let me change, even though there is "Modify" button on the project General Information page.

Comment: It seems to be a technical issue. Could you please provide the log so that we can analyze it to see where the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is

> I cannot send to nor receive from phones inside China

"inside China" means

> mobile phones physically located in China，but I could not send to or
> receive from phones located in China

You need to change a data storage location. Some development services provided by AppGallery Connect require you to select data storage locations for your project. These data storage locations determine the infrastructure used by AppGallery Connect to provide the services for your project. In addition, relevant data of your project will be stored on and processed by servers at these locations.  You currently selected Germany. If your app will provide services in the Chinese mainland, select China as the data storage location.

**1. Data Storage Location Distribution**

AppGallery Connect provides the following locations for you to choose from:
China, Germany, Russia, Singapore

**2. Setting a Data Storage Location**: Going to Project Setting > Convention for Settings

- Sign in to [AppGallery Connect](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/service/josp/agc/index.html) and select **My projects**.
- Select the project for which you want to set the data storage location from the project list.
- Go to Project **Setting** > **Convention**, click **Set** next to **Data storage location** under **Project**, and select a data storage location in the displayed dialog box.

**3. Changing a Data Storage Location**

A. Changing the Data Storage Location in AppGallery Connect

If no app has been released in the project and you have not subscribed to any paid plan related to the data storage location, you can change the data storage location in AppGallery Connect. The procedure is as follows:

1. Sign in to [AppGallery Connect](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/service/josp/agc/index.html) and select **My projects**.
2. Find your project from the project list and click the app for which you need to change the data storage location on the project card.
3. Go to **Project Setting** > **Convention** and click **Modify** next to **Data storage location** under **Project**.
4. Confirm information in the displayed **Information** dialog box, select the operation items, and click **Agree and Continue**. To cancel the modification, click **Cancel**.
5. In the displayed dialog box, set a new data storage location and click **OK**.

Note 1: After the data storage location is changed, the enabled services cannot be used. To use these services, you need to enable them again.

Note 2: The interval for changing the data storage location cannot be less than 1 hour. Otherwise, the system displays a message indicating that the change is too frequent and you need to try again later.

B. Changing the Data Storage Location by Submitting a Ticket: If an app has been released in the project or you have subscribed to a paid plan related to the data storage location, you cannot change the data storage location in AppGallery Connect. To change the data storage location in this case, you need to submit a ticket. Huawei will get back to you in 1 to 2 working days. The procedure is as follows:

1. Go to **Project Setting** > **Convention** and click **Modify** next to **Data storage location** under **Project**.
2. A dialog box is displayed, indicating the reason why the modification is not supported and prompting you to submit a ticket for processing. Confirm and select the operation items, and click **Create work order**.
3. On the **Submit ticket online** page, click **AppGallery Connect**.
4. In the dialog box that is displayed, select the service for which you need to change the data storage location.
5. Configure required information and click **Submit**.

**Notice:**
If you have enabled HUAWEI Push Kit, the following dialog box is displayed, prompting you to disable it and then change the data storage location. For details, please refer to [Enabling Services](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/app/agc-enable_service). Do not enable HUAWEI Push Kit again before confirming that the data storage location is successfully changed.

For more information, see [docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/app/agc-data-storage-location#h1-1586313685285-0).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is helpful.